# number pattern program wont add anymore outputs?

Tags: java

I'm supposed to have four patterns in a single program but the program won't output anything past my 2nd for statement. Can someone take a look at this please? Line RIGHT after Pattern C is where it stops outputting.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Patterns
 {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.print("Enter a positive maximum integer value: ");
     int max = input.nextInt();

     //1st Pattern
     System.out.println("\nPattern A: ");

     for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++){

        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){ 
        System.out.print(j + " ");
     }
        System.out.println();
     }

     //2nd Pattern         
     System.out.println("\nPattern B:");

     for (int i = -5; i <= max; i++, max--){

        for (int j = 1; j <= max; j++){
        System.out.print(j + " ");
   } 
       System.out.println();
   }

     // 3rd pattern and WHERE PROBLEM STARTS!!
     System.out.println("\nPattern C:");
     for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){

        for (int j = i; j < 0; j++){
        System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
     }
   }
```

Are my loops nested improperly?

My program asks the user for a max integer and makes a program based on that

here are some sample outputs

Enter a positive maximum integer value:  6

```
Pattern A:
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6


Pattern B:
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2
1


Pattern C:
          1
        2 1
      3 2 1
    4 3 2 1
  5 4 3 2 1
6 5 4 3 2 1


Pattern D:
1 2 3 4 5 6
  1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4
      1 2 3
        1 2
          1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
        for (int j = i; j < 0; j++){
```

`i` and `j` both start off at 0. `0` can never be less than `0`, so your `j` loop will never execute.

The other issue is that you're reusing the `max` variable after Pattern B has altered the value of it. You should copy the value of `max` into a variable that you can modify within the pattern without affecting the original.

For Pattern C, the loop is not executing because of your conditional and the fact that you've altered `max`.

Swap B and C with this.

```
    //2nd Pattern         
    System.out.println("\nPattern B:");
    int patternBMax = max;
    for (int i = -5; i <= patternBMax; i++, patternBMax--)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= patternBMax; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    // 3rd pattern and WHERE PROBLEM STARTS!!
    System.out.println("\nPattern C:");
    int patternCMax = max;
    for (int i = 1; i <= patternCMax; i++)
    {
        // Pad the output with the necessary whitespace
        for (int j = 0; j < patternCMax - i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }

        for (int k = i; k > 0; k--)
        {
            System.out.print(k + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

and you should get this

```
Pattern B:
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 
1 2 
1 

Pattern C:
          1 
        2 1 
      3 2 1 
    4 3 2 1 
  5 4 3 2 1 
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: it's not running as an endless loop. For pattern C I also changed the values from 0 to 1 just to test and nothing it outputting past "Pattern C".

Comment: I even copy and pasted one of my previous pattern statements and it wont print those for pattern C either

Comment: @neito, should have clarified. It never executes, which is why it doesn't output anything. The endless loop would happen if the `if` statement did work, because no positive number is ever less than 0.  You need to fix the `j < 0` conditional.

Comment: @neito, what pattern are you trying to print?

Comment: I tried that. It still doesn't print anything after the words "Pattern C"

Comment: all of them. I am even going to write a statement for a Pattern D so I will be printing 4 patterns in total. Pattern A & B print just fine.

Comment: @neito, I meant what should the pattern look like? What end result are you trying to achieve? A picture or something would help, you should edit your question to add it in.

Comment: @neito, see edit. There may be a syntax issue or two since I don't have a java compiler. You should be able to figure out D from there.

Comment: ohhhhhh ok, Thanks so much man! I would upvote you but stack won't let me yet haha.